# jQuery variable contains " and '

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it at all possible to replace the `'` in the postbody variable with `&#39;` without actually editing the postbody variable contents

```
var postbody = '<div class="postbody">this is tom's and bill's post</div>';
var postid = $('#post-content');
postid.append(postbody);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nVrZ/

Comment: your code isn't even a valid js...

Comment: First escape the `'` or your JavaScript string breaks: `\'`.

Comment: the correct appostophe is ` not  ' (single quote)

Comment: @Elen, I believe `’` [U+2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) is the correct apostrophe, not [U+0060](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an element and set its text, then you don't have to encode it:

```
var post = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'postbody' });
post.text("this is tom's and bill's post");
$('#post-content').append(post);​
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the anwer.

Comment: +1 - It's absolutely more readable than escaping quotes : p.s. You're missing a `)`

Comment: because i was asking if it's possible to replace the single quotes in a string of the postbody variable without having the need to change the content of it

Comment: @Yusaf your `postbody` variable, as it is, it needs to be changed in some way, you cannot avoid it.

Comment: @Yusaf: Your code to create the variable doesn't even run, so it has to be changed whatever you do.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
var postbody = '<div class="postbody">this is tom\'s and bill\'s post</div>';
```

or

```
var postbody = "<div class=\"postbody\">this is tom's and bill's post</div>";
```

Comment: sorry i forogot to mention, is it possible to do it without editing the postbody string

Comment: where do you get `post` from php or written by you?

Comment: for blogger where the content is given by <data:post.body/>

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to replace something in a string, just use replace():

```
var postbody = "<div class=\"postbody\">this is tom's and bill's post</div>";
postbody = postbody.replace(/\'/g, "&#39;");
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
var postbody = "<div class='postbody'>this is tom's and bill's post</div>";
var postid = $('#post-content');
postid.append(postbody);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/3nVrZ/1/